# How to create a session for user system in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables

I am trying to create a session for my system of users but I do not manage in any way to implement the sessions and it returns me that they are not defined.

I am currently using express-session, body-parser and cookie-parser.

I have tried to implement the session variables from my app.js file, invoke it to my access file and I still get an error of variable without defining

my varaibles of app.js

```js
app.use(cookieParser());
const redis = new connectRedis(session);
app.use(session({ store : new redis, saveUninitialized: true, resave: true, secret: 'it*SFVse', ttl : 3600, cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 * 24 * 7 } }));
app.use(connectFlash());
```

my post form

```js
if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, result[0].password)) {
message = 'Welcome';
req.session.user = 1;
res.render('index.ejs', {
message,
title: "Login",
});
}
```

my index.js

```js
getIndex: (req, res) => {
if (typeof req.session.user === 'undefined') { session = 'no session' } else { session = "session"; }
res.render('index.ejs', {
title: "Login",
message: '',
session
});
}
```

TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.

Comment: Why this `session = 'no session'`?  It appears like `session` may already be defined and `const`.

Comment: Is only my var for print data in .ejs file

Comment: Show us more of the surrounding code, including the whole request handler if you want us to be able to help.  This is insufficient code.  My guess is that you need to declare a local variable for `session` and name it something different, but I can't see enough of the code to know for sure.